# how to split scala string with regular expression

Tags: scala

I come up a pattern like 
`val pattern = "(\\w+)\\|(.*)\\|\\[(.*)\\]\\|\"(.*)\"\\|\"(.*)\"\\|\\[(.*)\\]\\|\\[(.*)\\]\\|(.*)\\|\\[(.*)\\]\\|\\[(.*)\\]".r`

and I have a original string

```
var str = """AuthLogout|vmlxapp21a|[13/Jan/2016:16:33:15 +0100]|"66.77.444.44 uid=XXXXX,ou=People,o=Bank,o=External,dc=xxxx,dc=com"|"abcd_123_portalweb_w  "|[]|[41]||[]|[]"""
```

then apply pattern to the string, but it is always empty.

`val items = pattern.findAllIn(str).toList`

Comment: Don't escape '\' brackets `[]` and ors `|`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, perhaps using a giant regex isn't the easiest way: You can `split` by `|` and get rid of the unwanted separators (`[`, `]`, `"`) using `replaceAll`:

```
val str = """AuthLogout|vmlxapp21a|[13/Jan/2016:16:33:15 +0100]|"66.77.444.44 uid=XXXXX,ou=People,o=Bank,o=External,dc=xxxx,dc=com"|"abcd_123_portalweb_w  "|[]|[41]||[]|[]"""
val withoutBoundaries = str.replaceAll("[\"\\]\\[]","")
val result = withoutBoundaries.split("\\|")
result.foreach(println)
```

Which prints:

```
AuthLogout
vmlxapp21a
13/Jan/2016:16:33:15 +0100
66.77.444.44 uid=XXXXX,ou=People,o=Bank,o=External,dc=xxxx,dc=com
abcd_123_portalweb_w  

41
```

If you *do* want to use a regex here, I'd create sub-regex vars representing the different text parts that you're after, to make this somewhat manageable:

```
val plain = "(.*)"              // no boundary characters
val boxed = s"\\[$plain\\]"     // same, encapsulated by square brackets
val quoted = '"' + plain + '"'  // same, encapsulated by double quotes

// the whole thing, separated by pipes:
val r = s"$plain\\|$plain\\|$boxed\\|$quoted\\|$quoted\\|$boxed\\|$boxed\\|$plain\\|$boxed\\|$boxed".r

val result = r.findAllIn(str).toList // this list has one item, as expected.
```

Now, if you want to see how this regex looks like, here it is - but I don't recommend having this in your code...:

```
val r = """(.*)\|(.*)\|\[(.*)\]\|"(.*)"\|"(.*)"\|\[(.*)\]\|\[(.*)\]\|(.*)\|\[(.*)\]\|\[(.*)\]""".r
```